# How can I prove mental harassment due to mind games and too much manipulation?

Tags: human-resources, politics, harassment, uae

I am working in a Startup Company of 10 members. While working for the last 2 years, I observed that my manager and some of teammates are doing lots of manipulation and mind games get a lot of possible complex work from me, to achieve deadlines (as they know my work speed is fast), and give me less financial growth after delivering the work.

This situation started when all of the employees got to know each other's salary and I am the highest paid employee (excluding the manager). The employees are asking for the same kind of salary as I am getting, as they also have the same number of years of experience (but not skills). Any startup company is afraid about exposing their business and we are a growing company. My manager and owner are afraid about it.

I never showed these kind of threats to my company and always accepted whatever they are giving me but they are putting a lot of workload on me. On the other side my manager has giving me a sign that he wishes to grow the others as he wants to resolve all conflicts but this thing will restrict my financial growth.

All teammates are connected with the manager via WhatsApp to pass all possible information which I am telling to the teammates (like if I have loan or there are some best approaches which I can improve our software).

When I had some loans from the bank and some of my teammates informed my manager about it, they put extreme work pressure on me to deliver all possible kinds of work. They are verbally talking a lot of time to replace teammates by hiring others by giving visual indication to me. They are trying to threat me about my jobs and trying to put pressure on my head to deliver all possible work. These kind of thing put me many times in mental stress

Regarding that I already complained to HR but I did not get any satisfactory. These kind of thing called leg pulling or mental harassment

Please suggest me what I have to do. How I can prove mental harassment because of verbal manipulation, mind game or drama?

Comment: Please could you edit the question so that it has paragraphs

Comment: How on Earth did they find out about your bank loan?

Comment: I have shared that thing to one of teammate

Comment: In future do not share anything about your finances with anybody

Comment: And how did people's salary levels get disclosed?  Normally that's confidential information.  No one in my teams knows my salary except for my superiors.

Comment: Which country are you in?

Comment: @HarlyK - Based on [another question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/70140/bonus-calculations), I assume UAE.

Comment: Yes I agreed , Honestly I have developed their software product by doing day and night handwork, My manger said to me people are manipulating me because i am easily manipulated but that does not mean they will do manipulation by ignoring my efforts or restricting my financial growth after successful project

Comment: This company is in UAE .if this will be in USA or other country then things will be different

Comment: Let's split this out.  Do you feel you're being victimised based on your work ethic, or because of your salary?

Comment: Pete: My salary ,According to my work ethics , I always appreciated many times on emails

Comment: I agreed I did mistake but what you suggest me now.This is great lesson for me

Comment: Maybe it is a language issue but you seem to be terribly stressed. I know that there is a lot of tabu about mental health, buy maybe you should consider visiting professional help (a psycologist or other terapist, for example) to help you relieve your stress before it becomes too much to bear.

Comment: I am not too much stressed but I have to take decision about my future plan: either quit or continue with them in mainupluative work environment . This situation happened first time with me where people make group with manger to do leg pulling of other employee to get just some pay raise.But this is great learning for me .Never ever share your secrets with any one including salary...

Comment: Honestly I have not discussed about it with lawyer till now.but now I have appointment with lawyer regarding this matter.According to open community forums experts, they can only try to put case to restrict my visa for other employer by filing case but 100% ,in court final decision will be in my favor as no body can restrict to anyone to work in whole country and second non competition is generally for less duration n some state rather than whole country...

Comment: I don't honestly see the harassment here. If you are the highest paid person, you are going to be expected to produce the most anywhere and get the most difficult tasks and have the most deadline pressure. That's why they pay you more.

Comment: I am agree to deliver things but mindgame,too much manipulations,job threat create unnecessary mental stress which should not happen at any worplace..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## You're stuck in this situation now

Now that the disparity of salary levels are in the open within your team, it's natural for your lower paid colleagues to feel aggrieved.  Whatever you do to try and force a softer view of yourself isn't likely to work.

This situation will most probably remain until the team splits up or there's a salary review that levels the pay grade, or you're promoted sideways into another team.

I don't see any easy way out of this dynamic, and this is why pay levels are largely confidential in nature.

Comment: @Rakesh - It might be an idea to wait about 24 hours before tagging an answer.  It's possible that other people might wish to provide different answers that could suit you better.

Comment: Thanks Pete. Because these things, I have resigned one time as i got better opportunity but their work depends on me at that time so HR told me that I have signed NON COMPITATION AGREEMENT In which they have mentioned That I am not allowed to join any cpmpitaiator in name of computer software house next 2 year in UAE.

Comment: "To refrain from directly or indirectly competing with the Employer or working for another competing organisation in the practice of Computer Software House within UAE for a period of 24 months (not exceeding 24 calendar months) following the expiration or termination of the Emptoyment Contract. "

Comment: @Pᴇᴛᴇ You rail against sharing salary info with colleagues for the reasons OP experiences, but this is an extreme case. In most cases, salary sharing is BETTER for the workplace, as seen [here in this video from my favourite opinion challenger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7xH7eGFuSYI)

Comment: @RakeshGaur I'd check with a lawyer about the non compete. Normally they aren't worth the paper they are written on.

Comment: @Snowlockk one thing is sure, they can't force you to sign that after you resigned.

Comment: I have signed non competition at the time of accepting employment offer.now according to that I can not join any IT company as all IT companies are computer software house but as far as my knowledge I can.join any other IT companies who are not dealing with same kind of clients or domain...Am I right?

Comment: @RakeshGaur, only a lawyer can tell you what you can legally do with the non-compete or whether it is enforceable as it is worded. In the future however, I would never consider signing a document that might have such severe limits on your employability. In fact I woudl ask to see the non-compete if they have one before accepting an offer.